# page--front.tpl.php not working

Tags: theming

I have omega 4 installed as my sub-theme, in which i have a custom layout. Now i am trying to make my home page custom, for which i have defined page--front.tpl.php in my templates/system folder, but its not working. I did explored the drupal questions/answers but nothing worked for me. I also tried to add

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = array('page__front');
```

But it doesn't seems to be working either. How do i make it work, please help??

Comment: Yes it seems an omega 4 issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to specify a suggestion for the front page, it is already one.

The only thing you have to do is create page--front.tpl.php and clear your cache.

See the [list of template suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656).

Then if it doesn't work then something else in your setup is interfering somehow but we don't know much about your site so it's hard to debug from there.

Comment: thank you for the response, i have already created page-front.tpl.php in my template/system folder, also tried by shifting it in my layout folder as main tpl file is right now controlling from layouts, also checked that suggestion have 'page__front' in it.. I have some blocks which are set to show on <front> only can this be an issue?

Comment: And ofcourse i have been clearing cache after creating tpl files, but thats not the case here, there is something else i am missing..not sure if layouts have something to do with this..?

Comment: Actually it seems this is an omega 4 issue. I will comment at the top under your question.